# Classic email templates are not available in the setup navigation even though I switch to Classic

Tags: configuration, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I reviewed the profile system permissions already. Manage Classic email Templates is already enabled. I used to make changes and create new templates previously. Suddenly the classic email Templates disappeared from navigation items. eventhough I switch from lightning to classic templates are visible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

noticed this same thing today while working in Trailhead.

To resolve, switch to Classic, then go to setup and search for "Classic Email Templates".